# Why is the last column of my footer distorted to the far right?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I've got this footer code I got off the Zurb website and I edited it and played with it to make it what I needed. But now I've got a problem.

[image]

See how the News & Media column is shoved far to the right? Can anyone help me fix my code?

HTML

```
   <footer class="footer">
  <div class="row full-width">
      <h4>Looking for Something?</h4>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns">
      <div class="sitemap">
          <h5>C-A-L Innovations</h5>
        <ul class="footer-links">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://calinnovations.wordpress.com/">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns">
      <div class="sitemap">
          <h5>Understanding CALi</h5>
        <ul class="footer-links">
        <li><a href="pandp.html">Purpose & People</a></li>
        <li><a href="core.html">Core Strengths</a></li>
        <li><a href="dream.html">The Dream</a></li>
        <li><a href="policies.html">Policies</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns">
      <div class="sitemap">
          <h5>Innovations</h5>
        <ul class="footer-links">
        <li><a href="kinkless.html">Kinkless</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon.html">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns">
      <div class="sitemap">
          <h5>News & Media</h5>
        <ul class="footer-links">
        <li><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="press.html">Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
    /* Footer Styles */
    .full-width {
      max-width: 1400px;
    }

    .footer {
      background-color: #016B98;
      padding: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .footer h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
    }

    .footer h5 {
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    .footer li {
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    .footer a {
    color: white;
    }

    .footer a:hover {
    color: #BCD955;
    }

    .footer a:visited {
    color: #FF859C
    }

    .footer li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    .footer h4 {
    color: #BCD955;
    }

.footer .sitemap{
text-align: left;
}
```

Please & thank you for your help!

Comment: this code is not enough for us. i tried to create a jsfiddle, but we need more information, because the footer items appeares below each others. Create a jsfiddle for us please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT looks like you are using a grid, and you have four columns.

`div class="small-6 medium-3 large-2 columns">`

for small you have 6 `small-6`, so each group will take up one half of the page.

for medium you have 3 `medium-3`, so each group will take up 1/4 of the page.

But for large: you have `large-2`, which means you have an additional blank space. (2, 4, 6, 8)

Try setting the `large-2` to `large-3` and see if that helps.

I do believe that is the problem with this one.

Comment: You're so right! I've been staring at this project for so long that simple things like that are slipping me by. Thank you!